# Ionic - Problemas ao Puxar Dados do Banco de Dados PHP

Tags: php, android, ionic, angular, ionic3

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso puxar os dados do banco de dados já com as tags em html.

eu pucho os dados e eles vem normalmente, porem ha minha tabela é composta por titulo, conteúdo e nesse conteúdo coloquei textos desse jeito:

```
<p>exemplo</p><p>exemplo</p><p><strong>exemplo</strong></p><p>exemplo</p>
```

quando puxo ele no ionic com:

```
<div id="adwaa4fs"> {{dados[0].conteudo}} </div>
```

ele mostra na tela:

```
<p>exemplo</p><p>exemplo</p><p><strong>exemplo</strong></p><p>exemplo</p>
```

e queria que ele mostrasse: 
exemplo
exemplo
**exemplo**
exemplo

tipo já com as tags html funcionado, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Pelo que parece, as *tags* do já estão funcionando. Se você está tentando exibir esse conteúdo: `<p>exemplo</p><p>exemplo</p><p><strong>exemplo</strong></p><p>exemplo</p>` as linhas vão se quebrar mesmo, pois você está inserindo vários parágrafos `<p>`. Pra ficar tudo na mesma linha teria que mudar isso pra algo como: `<p>exemplo exemplo exemplo <strong>exemplo</strong> exemplo</p>`.

Comment: eu quero exibir quebrado mas o ionic n está quebrando está mostrando tudo em uma linha

Comment: desculpe eu expliquei errado no post, já editei ele

Comment: Sem problemas. Dê uma olhada nesse link e veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759693/render-html-content-in-ionic-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use essa propriedade: `[innerHTML]`

```
<div [innerHTML]="dados[0].conteudo"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigada, salvou meu dia amigo